# kubernetes helm, jenkins lost token

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-helm

I'v had jenkins deployment from helm charts, did by colleague a month ago. I'v been working on it and somehow lost the `jenkins-token-xxxx` secret, it's literally gone from the cluster any idea how to recover it, if possible? (the weird thing is I didn't delete it, it just dissapeared)

I did a quick `helm install stable/jenkins --name jenkins` on minikube to show what's missing

```
$ kubectl get secrets -o wide
NAME                  TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
default-token-lvkpt   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      6d19h
jenkins               Opaque                                2      18m
jenkins-token-rxh2d   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      18m <-------
```

On cluster:

```
$ kubectl get secrets
NAME                                                TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
default-token-xyzca                                 kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      yd
jenkins                                             Opaque                                2      yd
jenkins-nginx-nginx-ingress-backend-token-xxxx     kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      yd
jenkins-nginx-nginx-ingress-token-zzzz             kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      yd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run:

> kubectl get secret jenkins -oyaml

Comment: I went on to another problem but thanks for answer, will be usefull

Comment: ok! sorry, maybe you can can look for the secret in all namespaces: kubectl get secrets --all-namespaces